# How to fix no matching function for call in Arduino IDE?

Tags: arduino-ide

This is my first time using Arduino IDE, and after replacing the jsonBuffer with jsonDOcument, as jsonBuffer was an older version, instructed by the jsonarduino website, and i have received the error message, "no matching function for call to 'ArduinoJson6171_91::BasicJsonDocument<ArduinoJson6171_91::DefaultAllocator>::BasicJsonDocument()'"
What should I do?
This is my code:

```
#include <FS.h>
#include <ESP8266WiFi.h>
#include <ESP8266WebServer.h>
#include <RCSwitch.h>
#include <WiFiUdp.h>
#include <WiFiManager.h>
#include <ArduinoJson.h>
#include

#ifndef CALLBACKFUNCTION_H //this is the beginning of the callbackfunction script
#define CALLBACKFUNCTION_H

#include <Arduino.h>

typedef void (*CallbackFunction) ();

#endif //this is the end of the callbackfunction script

#ifndef SWITCH_H //this is the beginning of the switch script
#define SWITCH_H

#include <Arduino.h>
#include <ESP8266WiFi.h>
#include <ESP8266WebServer.h>
#include <WiFiUDP.h>
#include "CallbackFunction.h"

class Switch {
private:
ESP8266WebServer *server = NULL;
WiFiUDP UDP;
String serial;
String persistent_uuid;
String device_name;
unsigned int localPort;
CallbackFunction onCallback;
CallbackFunction offCallback;

    void startWebServer();
    void handleEventservice();
    void handleUpnpControl();
    void handleRoot();
    void handleSetupXml();
public:
Switch();
Switch(String alexaInvokeName, unsigned int port, CallbackFunction onCallback, CallbackFunction offCallback);
~Switch();
String getAlexaInvokeName();
void serverLoop();
void respondToSearch(IPAddress& senderIP, unsigned int senderPort);
};

#endif //this is the end of the switch script

#include "switch.h"
#include "UpnpBroadcastResponder.h"
#include "CallbackFunction.h"

UpnpBroadcastResponder upnpBroadcastResponder;

Switch *alexa_switch1 = NULL;
Switch *alexa_switch2 = NULL;
Switch *alexa_switch3 = NULL;
Switch *alexa_switch4 = NULL;
Switch *alexa_switch5 = NULL;

// Callback prototypes
void alexa_switch1On();
void alexa_switch1Off();
void alexa_switch2On();
void alexa_switch2Off();
void alexa_switch3On();
void alexa_switch3Off();
void alexa_switch4On();
void alexa_switch4Off();
void alexa_switch5On();
void alexa_switch5Off();

// Set Relay Pins
int relayOne = 12;
int relayTwo = 13;
int relayThree = 14;
int relayFour = 16;

// Names each relay/outlet/device is known by -- these are set during config
char alexa_name1[100] = "1";
char alexa_name2[100] = "2";
char alexa_name3[100] = "3";
char alexa_name4[100] = "4";
char alexa_name5[100] = "5";

const char* AP_Name = "EchoBase1";
char saved_ssid[100] = "";
char saved_psk[100] = "";

// Flag for saving config data
bool shouldSaveConfig = false;
bool forceConfigPortal = false;

WiFiManager wifiManager;

// RF Tooling - https://codebender.cc/sketch:80290#RCSwitch%20-%20Transmit%20(Etekcity%20Power%20Outlets).ino
RCSwitch RFSwitch = RCSwitch();
int RF_PULSE_LENGTH = 179; // Pulse length to use for RF transmitter
int RF_TX_PIN = 0; // Digital pin connected to RF transmitter
int RF_BIT_LENGTH = 24;

// RF Signals (varies per remote controlled plugin set)
unsigned long rc_codes[5][2] = {
// ON //OFF
{5313843, 5313852}, /* Outlet 1 /
{5313987, 5313996}, / Outlet 2 /
{5314307, 5314316}, / Outlet 3 /
{335107, 335116}, / Outlet 4 /
{341251, 341260}, / Outlet 5 */
};
// Callback notifying us of the need to save config
void saveConfigCallback () {
Serial.println("Should save config");
shouldSaveConfig = true;
}

void setup()
{
Serial.begin(115200);

// -- WifiManager handling

// 5-second delay in case you wish to observe boot-up
for(int i=0; i < 5; i++) {
Serial.print(".");
delay(1000);
}
Serial.println("Booting");

// Clean FS, for testing... consider enabling if jumper is in flash mode, etc.
// SPIFFS.format();

// Set the flash/boot pin for input so we can read if the jumper is present
pinMode(0, INPUT);
// If the jumper is in "flash" mode (i.e., pin 0 is grounded), we will be enabling the config portal
forceConfigPortal = (digitalRead(0) == 0);
if(forceConfigPortal) {
Serial.println("Jumper set for flash - will trigger config portal");
} else {
Serial.println("Jumper set for boot - will attempt autoconnect, else config portal");
}

// Read configuration from FS json
Serial.println("Mounting ESP8266 integrated filesystem...");
if (SPIFFS.begin()) {
Serial.println("Mounted file system");
if (SPIFFS.exists("/config.json")) {
Serial.println("Found existing config; reading file");
File configFile = SPIFFS.open("/config.json", "r");
if (configFile) {
Serial.println("Opened config file for reading");
size_t size = configFile.size();
Serial.print("File size (bytes) = ");
Serial.println(size);
// Allocate a buffer to store contents of the file.
std::unique_ptr<char[]> buf(new char[size]);
configFile.readBytes(buf.get(), size);
DynamicJsonDocument jsonDocument;
JsonObject& json = jsonDocument.parseObject(buf.get());
Serial.println("Parsed JSON content:");
json.printTo(Serial);
Serial.println();
if (json.success()) {
strcpy(alexa_name1, json["alexa_name1"]);
strcpy(alexa_name2, json["alexa_name2"]);
strcpy(alexa_name3, json["alexa_name3"]);
strcpy(alexa_name4, json["alexa_name4"]);
strcpy(alexa_name5, json["alexa_name5"]);
Serial.println("Parsed Alexa relay name #1: " + String(alexa_name1));
Serial.println("Parsed Alexa relay name #2: " + String(alexa_name2));
Serial.println("Parsed Alexa relay name CharlesJGantt#3: " + String(alexa_name3));
Serial.println("Parsed Alexa relay name CharlesJGantt#4: " + String(alexa_name4));
Serial.println("Parsed Alexa relay name CharlesJGantt#5: " + String(alexa_name5));
} else {
Serial.println("** ERROR ** Failed to load/parse JSON config");
}
} else {
Serial.println("No JSON file found in filesystem");
}
}
} else {
Serial.println("** ERROR ** Failed to mount ESP8266's integrated filesyste,m");
}

// The extra parameters to be configured (can be either global or just in the setup)
// After connecting, parameter.getValue() will get you the configured value
// id/name placeholder/prompt default length
WiFiManagerParameter custom_alexa_name1("alexa_name1", "Device #1 name", alexa_name1, 100);
WiFiManagerParameter custom_alexa_name2("alexa_name2", "Device #2 name", alexa_name2, 100);
WiFiManagerParameter custom_alexa_name3("alexa_name3", "Device CharlesJGantt#3 name", alexa_name3, 100);
WiFiManagerParameter custom_alexa_name4("alexa_name4", "Device CharlesJGantt#4 name", alexa_name4, 100);
WiFiManagerParameter custom_alexa_name5("alexa_name5", "Device CharlesJGantt#5 name", alexa_name5, 100);

// Set the function that will be called to save the custom parameter after config
wifiManager.setSaveConfigCallback(saveConfigCallback);

// Hand the parameter defintions to the WifiManager for use during config
wifiManager.addParameter(&custom_alexa_name1);
wifiManager.addParameter(&custom_alexa_name2);
wifiManager.addParameter(&custom_alexa_name3);
wifiManager.addParameter(&custom_alexa_name4);
wifiManager.addParameter(&custom_alexa_name5);

//reset settings - for testing
//wifiManager.resetSettings();

//set minimu quality of signal so it ignores AP's under that quality
//defaults to 8%
//wifiManager.setMinimumSignalQuality();

//sets timeout until configuration portal gets turned off
//useful to make it all retry or go to sleep
//in seconds
//wifiManager.setTimeout(120);

if(forceConfigPortal) {
wifiManager.setSTAStaticIPConfig(IPAddress(10,0,1,99), IPAddress(10,0,1,1), IPAddress(255,255,255,0));
// Force config portal while jumper is set for flashing
if (!wifiManager.startConfigPortal(AP_Name)) {
Serial.println("** ERROR ** Failed to connect with new config / possibly hit config portal timeout; Resetting in 3sec...");
delay(3000);
//reset and try again, or maybe put it to deep sleep
ESP.reset();
delay(5000);
}
} else {
// Autoconnect if we can

// Fetches ssid and pass and tries to connect; if it does not connect it starts an access point with the specified name
// and goes into a blocking loop awaiting configuration
if (!wifiManager.autoConnect(AP_Name)) {
  Serial.println("** ERROR ** Failed to connect with new config / possibly hit timeout; Resetting in 3sec...");
  delay(3000);
  //reset and try again, or maybe put it to deep sleep
  ESP.reset();
  delay(5000);
}
}

// --- If you get here you have connected to the WiFi ---
Serial.println("Connected to wifi");
// Save the connect info in case we need to reconnect
WiFi.SSID().toCharArray(saved_ssid, 100);
WiFi.psk().toCharArray(saved_psk, 100);

// Read updated parameters
strcpy(alexa_name1, custom_alexa_name1.getValue());
strcpy(alexa_name2, custom_alexa_name2.getValue());
strcpy(alexa_name3, custom_alexa_name3.getValue());
strcpy(alexa_name4, custom_alexa_name4.getValue());
strcpy(alexa_name5, custom_alexa_name5.getValue());
Serial.println("Read configured Alexa relay name #1: " + String(alexa_name1));
Serial.println("Read configured Alexa relay name #2: " + String(alexa_name2));
Serial.println("Read configured Alexa relay name CharlesJGantt#3: " + String(alexa_name3));
Serial.println("Read configured Alexa relay name CharlesJGantt#4: " + String(alexa_name4));
Serial.println("Read configured Alexa relay name CharlesJGantt#5: " + String(alexa_name5));

// Save the custom parameters to the ESP8266 filesystem if changed
if (shouldSaveConfig) {
Serial.println("Saving config to ESP8266 filesystem");
DynamicJsonDocument jsonDocument;
JsonObject& json = jsonDocument.createObject();
json["alexa_name1"] = alexa_name1;
json["alexa_name2"] = alexa_name2;
json["alexa_name3"] = alexa_name3;
json["alexa_name4"] = alexa_name4;
json["alexa_name5"] = alexa_name5;
Serial.println("Attempting to open config JSON file for writing");
File configFile = SPIFFS.open("/config.json", "w");
if (!configFile) {
Serial.println("** ERROR ** Failed to open JSON config file for writing");
} else {
json.printTo(Serial);
Serial.println();
json.printTo(configFile);
configFile.close();
Serial.println("File write complete");
}
}

Serial.print("SSID: " );
Serial.println(WiFi.SSID());
Serial.print("Local IP: ");
Serial.println(WiFi.localIP());

// -- ALEXA setup/handling --

upnpBroadcastResponder.beginUdpMulticast();

// Define your switches here. Max 14
// Format: Alexa invocation name, local port no, on callback, off callback
alexa_switch1 = new Switch(alexa_name1, 80, alexa_switch1On, alexa_switch1Off);
alexa_switch2 = new Switch(alexa_name2, 81, alexa_switch2On, alexa_switch2Off);
alexa_switch3 = new Switch(alexa_name3, 82, alexa_switch3On, alexa_switch3Off);
alexa_switch4 = new Switch(alexa_name4, 83, alexa_switch4On, alexa_switch4Off);
alexa_switch5 = new Switch(alexa_name5, 85, alexa_switch5On, alexa_switch5Off);

Serial.println("Adding switches upnp broadcast responder");
upnpBroadcastResponder.addDevice(*alexa_switch1);
upnpBroadcastResponder.addDevice(*alexa_switch2);
upnpBroadcastResponder.addDevice(*alexa_switch3);
upnpBroadcastResponder.addDevice(*alexa_switch4);
upnpBroadcastResponder.addDevice(*alexa_switch5);

// Setup RF Transmitter
RFSwitch.enableTransmit(RF_TX_PIN);
RFSwitch.setPulseLength(RF_PULSE_LENGTH);
}

/* If disconnected from Wifi, enter a blocking loop that periodically attempts reconnection */
void reconnectIfNecessary() {
while(WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED) {
Serial.println("Disconnected; Attempting reconnect to " + String(saved_ssid) + "...");
WiFi.disconnect();
WiFi.mode(WIFI_AP_STA);
WiFi.begin(saved_ssid, saved_psk);
// Output reconnection status info every second over the next 10 sec
for( int i = 0; i < 10 ; i++ ) {
delay(1000);
Serial.print("WiFi status = ");
if( WiFi.status() == WL_CONNECTED ) {
Serial.println("Connected");
break;
} else {
Serial.println("Disconnected");
}
}
if(WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED) {
Serial.println("Failure to establish connection after 10 sec. Will reattempt connection in 2 sec");
delay(2000);
}
}
}

void loop()
{
// Ensure wifi is connected (won't return until it has connected)
reconnectIfNecessary();
// Respond to any Alexa/discovery requests
upnpBroadcastResponder.serverLoop();
// Respond to any UPnP control requests
alexa_switch1->serverLoop();
alexa_switch2->serverLoop();
alexa_switch3->serverLoop();
alexa_switch4->serverLoop();
alexa_switch5->serverLoop();
}

void alexa_switch1On() {
Serial.println("Switch 1 turn on ...");
enableOutlet(1, true);
}
void alexa_switch1Off() {
Serial.println("Switch 1 turn off ...");
enableOutlet(1, false);
}

void alexa_switch2On() {
Serial.println("Switch 2 turn on ...");
enableOutlet(2, true);
}
void alexa_switch2Off() {
Serial.println("Switch 2 turn off ...");
enableOutlet(2, false);
}

void alexa_switch3On() {
Serial.println("Switch 3 turn on ...");
enableOutlet(3, true);
}
void alexa_switch3Off() {
Serial.println("Switch 3 turn off ...");
enableOutlet(3, false);
}

void alexa_switch4On() {
Serial.println("Switch 4 turn on ...");
enableOutlet(4, true);
}
void alexa_switch4Off() {
Serial.println("Switch 4 turn off ...");
enableOutlet(4, false);
}

void alexa_switch5On() {
Serial.println("Switch 5 turn on ...");
enableOutlet(5, true);
}
void alexa_switch5Off() {
Serial.println("Switch 5 turn off ...");
enableOutlet(5, false);
}

void enableOutlet(int outletNumber, bool onOrOff)
{
if (outletNumber < 1 || outletNumber > 5) {
Serial.println("Invalid outlet number");
return;
}

unsigned long *onOffCodes = rc_codes[outletNumber - 1];
unsigned long codeToSend = onOffCodes[onOrOff ? 0 : 1];
RFSwitch.send(codeToSend, RF_BIT_LENGTH);

char outletNumberString[1];
int retVal = snprintf(outletNumberString, 1, "%d", outletNumber);
if (retVal < 0) {
Serial.println("Log encoding error");
return;
}

Serial.print("Switch " + String(outletNumber) + " turned ");
if (onOrOff) {
Serial.println("on");
} else {
Serial.println("off");
}
}
```

Comment: this is from a Github project at https://github.com/alukach/Amazon-Alexa-RF-Outlets-Integration